# Box that expand in a gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to expand a box by the size some boxes inside a "gallery".
I need it the way it doesn't messy the other boxes neither the other page elements. It should expand and collapse.
There are eight boxes and when I click at one of them it should take the space of all the eight boxes, when I clik it again, it should collapse down to its original one-box-size. It should also show a different content for each box when expanded.
[image]

[image]

I tried to use css target properties and anchor tags.
What solution would you guys use?

here's my code trial:

```
<a href="#odontopediatria">
    <div class="trat-card">
        <div class="trat-icone"><i class="fas fa-tooth"></i></div>
        <div class="trat-titulo">Odontopediatria</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="odontopediatria">
        <div class="lightbox-conteudo">
            <div class="trat-texto">
                <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-3x"></i>
                <p>Odontopediatria é a especialidade que tem como objetivo o diagnóstico, a prevenção, o tratamento e o controle dos problemas de saúde bucal do bebê, da criança e do adolescente.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</a>


    
.lightbox {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox:target {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.lightbox div:nth-child(n) {
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 306px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I would use `position: absolute` + `javascript`

Comment: You are uses an embedded a-tag in another a-tag, that is invalid use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a demo of what you want, I use a small jQuery code for manage a togglable class which help to make CSS to expand small box to large.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expandable_box").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".main_col").toggleClass("expanded");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_container {
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.main_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0px -5px;
  position: relative;
}

.main_col {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main_col.expanded {
  position: absolute;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.expandable_box {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #3ca6b6;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.expanded .expandable_box {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0c798a;
}

.expandable_box h4 {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px;
}

.expandable_box p {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.expanded .expandable_box p {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .main_col {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Same Place Expander</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="main_row">
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_col">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expandable_box">
          <i class="fas fa-tooth fa-lg"></i>
          <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fringilla dapibus est, et cursus justo. Aenean lobortis porta nunc, nec ultricies lectus molestie id. Nulla sollicitudin elementum consectetur. Pellentesque gravida nunc eget efficitur vestibulum.
            In lorem lacus, maximus eu bibendum quis, fringilla at lectus. Vestibulum fringilla quam sed diam mattis, non congue arcu efficitur.
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a35ed2bddb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```css
  .container{
    display: flex;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  }
  .box{
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .box:active{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .box.box1{
    background-color: red;
  }
  .box.box2{
    background-color: greenyellow;
  }
  .box.box4{
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .box.box5{
    background-color: red;
  }
  .box.box6{
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .box.box3{
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .box1:active::after{
    content: 'some text for the box1';
      flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .box2:active::after{
    content: 'some text for the box2';
      flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .box3:active::after{
    content: 'some text for the box3';
      flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .box4:active::after{
    content: 'differnt text for box 4';
      flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .box5:active::after{
    content: 'hello there';
      flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .box6:active::after{
    content: 'ciao bello';
      flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  a{
      flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box box2"><a>box1</a></div>
    <div class="box box1"><a>box2</a></div>
    <div class="box box3"><a>box2</a></div>
    <div class="box box4"><a>box2</a></div>
    <div class="box box5"><a>box2</a></div>
    <div class="box box6"><a>box2</a></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: if you need them to stay open use Js to pass `flex: 0 0 100%` on click event. You could use a toggle class

Comment: Thank you very much. I really apreciate your time for doing that.